# How to parse ISO compliant string to Date using Java Time library

Tags: java, java-time, datetime-parsing, java.util.date

I have timestamp in various format, example:

```
2018-07-21T00:50:39
2017-11-20T23:18:27.529Z
```

I need to parse them to java.util.Date, and have tried the following approach, they both worked for the first format but failed the second one.

Here are the methods I tried and it's error:

**1.**

```
private Date try3(String dateString) {
        return Date.from(Instant.parse(dateString).atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant());
    }
```

it failed at first format, error:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-11-20T23:18:28' could not be parsed at index 19
```

**2.**

```
private Date try2(String dateString) {
    return Date.from(LocalDateTime.parse(dateString).atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant());
}
```

for second format, this method throw error:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-11-20T23:18:27.529Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 23
```

**3:**

```
private Date try1(String dateString) {
    return Date.from(ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString,
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))).toInstant());

}
```

for the second format, the above method throw error:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-11-20T23:18:27.529Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 19
```

I eventually ended up with **Joda library**:

```
private Date try4(String dateString) {
        return new DateTime(dateString).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).toDate();
    }
```

But really is there any way to do this in Java time library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always want to obtain the same type, and I seem to understand that if no offset is in the string, you want UTC (it’s important to be clear about this). I suggest specifying a formatter with optional UTC offset and a default of UTC (zero offset) in case there isn’t any offset in the string:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
            .appendPattern("[X]")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, 0)
            .toFormatter();

    String withoutZ = "2018-07-21T00:50:39";
    Instant anInstant = formatter.parse(withoutZ, Instant::from);
    System.out.println(anInstant);

    String withZ = "2017-11-20T23:18:27.529Z";
    Instant anotherInstant = formatter.parse(withZ, Instant::from);
    System.out.println(anotherInstant);
```

Output:

> ```
> 2018-07-21T00:50:39Z
> 2017-11-20T23:18:27.529Z
> ```

The square brackets in the format pattern string `[X]` denote that offset X is optional. The presence and absence of decimals on the seconds is handled by `ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`.

I hope that you are aware that the `Date` class is poorly designed and long outdated, so generally you shouldn’t want one, and that you are only asking for one because you indispensably need one for a legacy API that you cannot change just now. In this case do the final conversion from `Instant` as in your question.

The techniques generally used for variable date/time formats include:

1. Trying a number of known formats in turn.
2. Taking a taste of the string before determining which format to use. In your case you might have branched on `.endsWith("Z")` as already suggested in Basil Bourque’s answer.
3. Optional parts in the format pattern.
4. `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.parseDefaulting()` for parts that may be absent from the parsed string.
5. `DateTimeFormatter.parseBest()`.

As you have seen, I am using items 3. and 4. here.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

This has been covered countless times already. So search Stack Overflow for more info.

Never use `Date` or `Calendar`. Use only *java.time*. Likewise, Joda-Time is also supplanted by *java.time* (both being led by the same man, Stephen Colebourne).

Both your string inputs are in standard ISO 8601 format. The *java.time* classes use these formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

The first lacks an indicator of offset-from-UTC or time zone, so it does *not* represent a moment.

```
LocalDateTime.parse( "2018-07-21T00:50:39" )
```

The second in `Z` which means UTC, and is pronounced “Zulu”.

```
Instant.parse( "2017-11-20T23:18:27.529Z" )
```

To handle both formats in one method, search the input string for the presence of the `Z` and branch accordingly. Also, trap for the exception in case you receive unexpected inputs.

If you must have a `java.util.Date` object, see that class JavaDoc for new methods `from` & `to…` on the old classes that convert to/from the *java.time* classes. As I said, all this has been covered many many times, so search for more info.

Comment: I need one method to parse both strings, not two methods and one for each